# How to work on the same django project on two different machines?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have my Django project all saved in a virtual environment, and I'm using PostgreSQL. When I copied my virtual environment onto a second PC, I can not launch the project because of database authentication problems. I'm just wondering if it is possible to duplicate the project (with database) onto a second machine, and work on the development from two machines. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use vagrant for this. There's a certain amount of setup involved, but once you have that done, you can work on your project on any machine, as long as you can pull from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create database with all of your credentials that located in `settings.py` file. And if you want, copy data from db on the first computer with [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html) and then put that data on newly created database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common situation. You could use multiple setting files to achieve this.

Let's say your project is *myproject*:

so in `myproject/` you have:

```
- __init__.py
- urls.py
- wsgi.py
- settings.py
```

You could add a new file with your local configuration:

```
- local_settings.py
```

You can override database configuration in this file:

```
DATABASES = {
# 'default': {
#     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
# }
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'newdatabase',
    'USER': 'newuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'newpassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    # 'HOST': 'localhost', # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}

Then, add at the end of your original `settings.py` file:

```
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Everywhere you carry your project you can create a new `local_settings.py` file with any new config you need.

Remember you can ignore this file (`local_settings.py`) in your github repository, so when you clone you project in a new PC you will just need to create a new `local_settings.py` and make you project run.